# Most portable library for dynamic code generation?

Tags: c++, assembly, code-generation, cpu-architecture, machine-code

I'm looking for the most portable assembler library, like [asmjit](http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/) or [jitasm](http://code.google.com/p/jitasm/).

When I say 'most portable' I mean, that has the most support for a wide verity of architectures. Language doesn't matter so much, but C++ would be the best solution, especially when coupled with GCC.

Important architectures for me, are x86/64, PowerPC and ARM.

Answer (score 13):

[DynASM](http://luajit.org/dynasm.html), used by LuaJIT, supports x86, x64, ARM, MIPS and PowerPC.

Answer (score 7):

After extensive searching and research, I found LLVM to be the best JIT library. All of them support only x86/x86_64, and [LLVM](http://llvm.org/Features.html) is the only one with x86/x86_64 *and* PPC/PPC64.

So I hereby declare it the most portable...
If anyone finds a better one, please - oh please share.

Comment: It once was, but the success killed it for general JIT purposes. It is now way to fat, too complicated and too bound to static languages including C++

Answer (score 4):

Well GNU offers you [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/libjit-doc/libjit.html). [Highly portable](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/libjit-doc/libjit_20.html#SEC38) to your architectures of choice, well documented and offering a C++ interface. Being GCC your compiler, I can't think of a better offer.

Answer (score 2):

You might find [NanoJit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Nanojit) interesting. It's lighter than LLVM, although horribly underdocumented (there's a nice tutorial [here](http://bluishcoder.co.nz/2009/05/01/simple-nanojit-example.html)...and that's about it). Supported architectures:

- x86
- x64
- ARM
- MIPS
- PowerPC

Answer (score -6):

"x86/64, PowerPC and ARM" is not a very wide range of architectures. Many open source VMs should support that set, including Mono for one. What are you looking to do with it?

Mono's [supported platforms](http://www.mono-project.com/Supported_Platforms) for JIT include (partial list here - full list in link):

- X86
- X86-64
- IA64 (Itanium)
- Power PC
- ARM
- MIPS
- Alpha

Comment: jitasm will let you generate asm code on the fly with the option to execute it. Mono will compile code offline. Not really what I want.

Comment: Mono pre-compiles C# to IL and JITs the IL on the fly.

Comment: then I'd have to code a wrapper that compiles to IL. Not exactly efficient and is far off from what I requested.